# Upload of photos from cf card to pc is super slow

Tags: windows-7, memory, speed

I have a new custom built pc.  It has 8B of RAM and was working like a dream. Suddenly it is super slow and taking hours to download photos that used to take just minutes.  I notice that there is 8GB RAM but only 3,25GB usable.  could this be the problem? If so how to I change it? I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I'm guessing you have a 32-bit version of Windows 7?  That would explain why only 3.25 GB is usable.  But I doubt that has anything to do with the slow transfers.

How do you transfer your photos?  Do you plug a USB cable into the camera, or put the card in a card reader?

Answer (score 1):

To use all your RAM you need to install Windows 7 64-bit. The 32-bit image can only address up to 4GB (typically less with space reserved for view-port memory and other I/O space within the same 4GB). You cannot change between 32-/64-bit without reinstalling. This is likely not what is causing your download performance problem if you have not reinstalled since you got your system. Also, 32-bit Windows 7 performs well within 2-4GB.

To see if you have 32 or 64 bit installed, click Start, right-click Computer, and select Properties. Look at "System type:".

Download time is usually more a factor of the network interface.

Some things to check:

- Perhaps something changed externally; your provider?
- There could be a problem with the network drivers; get the latest version from the manufacturer of either the network card or your computer.
- Have you monitored the actual processes and network activity (right-click Taskbar [also called "Superbar"], select "Start Task Manager", click on "Resource Monitor...")? Perhaps you have a runaway program that is consuming the CPU, RAM or network resources.
- Your computer may have acquired a virus too; if you have A-V software, find another one and let it do a full scan for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're only getting a 1.1 speed connection from the USB connection rather than 2.0.

Are you plugging the camera (or card reader) into the same USB socket on the computer?

Try different sockets - do they all produce the same result?

You might need to reinstall the card reader or camera support software.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check in your computer's BIOS to make sure that the USB2.0 controller is enabled.  If it is not, the ports will only give 1.1 speeds.